# .net web app performing slowly on 64-bit windows / iis 7.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2005, win64, wow64

I've got a web app written in asp.net 3.5 / sql server 2005 and it runs extremely fast on my local machine (winXP) & test server (win2003) however some pages run very slowly when on the production server which is running win2008 r2.  The web app isn't compiled but it does use two 32-bit dll's (intelligencia urlrewriter & campaign monitor api).  I've configured iis7.5 to enable 32-bit apps for the application pool but this hasn't made a difference.  Also the pages in question don't use the dll's mentioned any more than any other pages which load fine.   The page in question does do very heavy database work so i'm thinking maybe it's got something to do with the fact the production server is running 32-bit sql!?!

Has anyone experience these symptoms or could anyone offer some advice on how i go about getting to the bottom of this?

Cheers

Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a performance profiler such as [dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/) or [Ants Performance profile](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/)r to profile your application and find the bottlenecks.

You point these tools at your application, let them run for a while and then check the performance statistics they provide in order to find what is being called and how long it takes.

In my experience, the whole 32bit running on 64bit is a red herring - chances are that the application or the database are doing something that is taking long and slowing things down.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Oded.  I'm going to download one of those performance profilers now and see what info they provide.  Do you know if I can point those tools at a web app that isn't compiled?

Comment: @tt83 - If you mean a web app that isn't _pre-compiled_, I believe they can be.